# Autofac: Relate LifeTimeScope to lifetime of ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, autofac

I am very surprised that this question is not covered in every IoC/MVVM tutorial, so hopefully I am missing something obvious.

In short, my question is: How can I relate an Autofac LifeTimeScope to the lifetime of a ViewModel.

Consider the simple application below.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                                          _ o x |
-------------------------------------------------
|          |                                     |
| Item A   |                                     |
| Item B   |       DetailView for Item A         |
| Item C   |                                     |
|          |                                     | 
|------------------------------------------------
```

This application consist of five views:

- MainView
- ListView
- ADetailView
- BDetailView
- CDetailView

as well as five viewmodels

- MainViewModel
- ListViewModel
- ADetalViewModel
- BDetalViewModel
- CDetalViewModel

The main view would be structured something like this.

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Column="0">
    </ListView>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Border Grid.Column="2">
        <Border.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ADetailViewModel}">
                <vw:ADetailView></vw:ADetailView>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BDetailViewModel}">
                <vw:BDetailView></vw:BDetailView>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CDetailViewModel}">
                <vw:CDetailView></vw:CDetailView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Border.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentDetailViewModel}"></ContentPresenter>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

So its a template drive user interface, where the template type will trigger a change to the correct view. To do this we must instantiate a ViewModel of the correct type and assign it to CurrentDetailViewModel in MainViewModel.

Now I arrive at the question. I would VERY much like the the creation of this detail viewmodel to also trigger the creation of a LifetimeScope. Then all of its dependencies will reside inside this scope and can easily be disposed of when switching to another view/viewmodel.

This has to be a very very very common use case for Autofac and I am very curious how other people approach it.

Comment: I'm not acquainted with Autofac, unfortunately but I think I generally understand what you are talking about. I always set the lifetime of dependencies in the bootstrapper. Why would you want to trigger some action on setting lifetime of dependencies in the runtime?

Comment: I am not talking about lifetime specification but rather creating a temporary lifetimescope that only exist while the detail view is visible. Unity has the Lifetime Managers but I am not sure it is exactly the same as lifetimescope. Imagine a web server, it creates a lifetimescope for each request, and if you resolve instances the normal behavior is for those instances to be created in this lifetimescope, and consequently disposed with it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have implementers which have unmanaged resources? (in other case I don't understand the reason why would you want that feature, since managed implementers will be garbage collected after ViewModel become unreachable). I need to understand WHY, preferably on a practical example, you want that feature, this can help me to help you, I hope)

Comment: At least in Autofac, because instances are created on a lifetimescope, nothing will be garbage collected before the lifetimescope is being garbage collected. So if the MainViewModel is created on the root lifetimescope then all its dependencies will not be garbage collected before root lifetimescope is removed.
Other than that, yes, many of my viewmodels hold handles etc that needs to be released.

Comment: If you have a ShellViewModel or some kind of a root ViewModel, then you can send a message via a message bus (EventAggregator), say, "ChangeView" (when you need to open a View) which you will handle within your root VM. Here you'll resolve and make all the needed setup. Is there something wrong with what suggest? (or you need more help on autofac, rather then how to organize the communication in MVVM?)

Comment: @EngineerSpock, Btw, don't feel you need to understand the specific example from Autofac point of view (despite the title). I am honestly looking for a conceptual solution to handle detail views and how to make sure they are garbage collected + disposed properly

Comment: 1. What's wrong with a MessageBus for having a central point for all the stuff? 2. You said "
   
 
At least in Autofac, because instances are created on a lifetimescope, nothing will be garbage collected before the lifetimescope is being garbage collected. ..... " What the hell is this? This is smth. horrible))) After rewriting the CurrentViewModel reference, ViewModel should become ready for GC. If I create with Windsor instance of ViewModels and then inject them into CurrentVM, they will be GC'ed as soon as CurrentViewModel rewrited by a new VM.

Comment: 1. I will give this another pass in the thinker. I disgarded it after short evaluation because many times I need direct access to child view model properties etc. 2. That is how it works. The container holds a reference to every instance created, and only by releasing the lifetimescope will the reference be removed and made ready for GC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113446/discussion-between-sunefred-and-engineerspock).

Answer (score 1):

I will add my current approach to the answer list and hopefully someone will add or give a better answer.

I made use of Owned. When the container find something declared as `Owned<>` it will create the instance in its own fresh lifetimescope. Any dependencies will then (by default) also end up in this lifetimescope. The lifetimescope has to be destroyed manually however by calling `Dispose()`. In the example below I combine Owned with Func to get a factory for creating any number of owned instances.

Constructor:

```
private readonly Func<Owned<ADetailViewModel> _aFactory;
private readonly Func<Owned<BDetailViewModel> _bFactory;
private readonly Func<Owned<CDetailViewModel> _cFactory;

private IDisposable _currentOwned;

public MainViewModel(Func<int, Owned<ADetailViewModel>> aFactory,
                     Func<int, Owned<BDetailViewModel>> bFactory,
                     Func<int, Owned<CDetailViewModel>> cFactory)
{
    _aFactory= aFactory;
    _bFactory= bFactory;
    _cFactory= cFactory;
}
```

SwitchDetailViewCommand:

```
private RelayCommand<IListItemViewModel> _switchDetailViewCommand ;
public RelayCommand<IListItemViewModel> SwitchDetailViewCommand 
{
    get
    {
        return _switchDetailViewCommand ?? (_switchDetailViewCommand = new RelayCommand<IListItemViewModel>(
            (listitem) =>
            {   
                if (_currentOwned != null)
                {
                    _currentOwned.Dispose();
                }   
                switch (listitem.Type)
                {
                    case "A":
                    {
                        var aOwned = _aFactory();
                        _currentOwned = aOwned;
                        CurrentDetailViewModel = _aOwned.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "B":
                    {
                        var bOwned = _bFactory();
                        _currentOwned = bOwned;
                        CurrentDetailViewModel = _bOwned.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                    case "C":
                    {
                        var cOwned = _cFactory();
                        _currentOwned = cOwned;
                        CurrentDetailViewModel = _cOwned.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        ));
    }
}
```